# How to prevent QSpinBox from automatically highlighting contents

Tags: qt, qt4, qspinbox

`QSpinBox` makes its contents selected (highlighted) upon using up/down buttons. Is there any way to disable this?
Is there any way to clear selection, other than use my own subclass of `QSpinBox` to access the underlying `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to directly disable it, but you can do a bit of a hack:

```
void Window::onSpinBoxValueChanged() // slot
{
    spinBox->findChild<QLineEdit*>()->deselect();
}
```

I recommend connecting to this using a queued connection, like this:

```
connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onSpinBoxValueChanged()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

This will ensure that the slot is called after the line edit is highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Same solution as @Anthony's, but shorter:

```cpp
connect(spinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), spinBox,
            [&, spinBox](){spinBox->findChild<QLineEdit*>()->deselect();}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```