# How to completely disable value highlighting of qspinboxes?

Tags: qt

Half of my answer was found here: [How to prevent QSpinBox from automatically highlighting contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892129/how-to-prevent-qspinbox-from-automatically-highlighting-contents)

However, the program still allows for a mouse or touch-drag to highlight the values of the spinboxes. I need absolutely no highlighting as my application is for an embedded device interface.

How do completely disable highlighting of any kind while still maintaining the spinbox up/down button functionality.

Comment: Does `spinBox->setReadOnly(true)` work?

Comment: No, it still highlights but now the up and down buttons no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we ended up doing was to connect a couple signals to the textEditDeselect slot.

```
foreach(QSpinBox* sb, ui.main->findChildren<QSpinBox*>())
{
    sb->findChildren<QLineEdit*> ().at(0)->setReadOnly(true);
    connect(sb,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SLOT(textEditDeselect()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(sb->findChild<QLineEdit*> (), SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(int,int)),this,  SLOT(textEditDeselect()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change the palette in Qt Designer.

Select qspinbox, click "Change Palette" and for **HighlightedText** choose black color. This will disable blue background, at least on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set the style sheet for the QSpinBox's QLineEdit. This effectively makes the selection color invisible.

Pyqt5:

```
tmpSpinBox = QSpinBox()
tmpSpinBox.linedit().setStyleSheet("""QLineEdit { 
                                       selection-background-color: white;
                                       selection-color: black 
                                   }""")
```